# (Case)controller.getRecord(); - Returning Null in the visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, attachment

I'm trying to get the record that starts a visualforce page but it's returning null.

Can anyone point out the problem to me?

Visualforce:

```xml
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="UploadAttachmentController">

 <apex:sectionHeader title="{!Case.CaseNumber}" subtitle="Attach File"/>
 
 <apex:form id="form_Upload">
 <apex:pageBlock >

 <apex:pageBlockButtons >
   <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Back to {!Case.CaseNumber}"/>
   <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Cancel"/>
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:pageMessages />
 
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file_File"/>
      <apex:inputFile id="file_File" value="{!fileBody}" filename="{!fileName}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Description" for="description"/> 
      <apex:inputTextarea id="description" value="{!description}" rows="4" cols="50"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="" for="uploadBtn"/> 
      <apex:commandButton id="uploadBtn" value="Attach File" action="{!processUpload}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    
    
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
 
 </apex:pageBlock>


 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

ApexController:

```java
public class UploadAttachmentController {
    
    /*
    Custom controller created in order to allow you to create custom attachments.
    */
    
    public String selectedType {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    private Case caso{get;set;}
    public String fileName {get;set;}
    public Blob fileBody {get;set;}
    
    public UploadAttachmentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        this.caso = (Case)controller.getRecord();
        System.debug(this.caso);
    }   
    
    // creates a new Juridical_Attachments__c record
    private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {
        Juridical_Attachments__c obj = new Juridical_Attachments__c();
        //obj.Case__c = caso.Id; 
        obj.Case__c = caso.id; 
        obj.description__c = description;
        // fill out cust obj fields
        return Database.insert(obj);
    }
    
    // create an actual Attachment record with the Juridical_Attachments__c as parent
    private Database.SaveResult saveStandardAttachment(Id parentId) {
        Database.SaveResult result;
        
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.body = this.fileBody;
        attachment.name = this.fileName;
        attachment.parentId = parentId;
        // inser the attahcment
        result = Database.insert(attachment);
        // reset the file for the view state
        fileBody = Blob.valueOf(' ');
        return result;
    }
    
    /**
    * Upload process is:
    *  1. Insert new Juridical_Attachments__c record
    *  2. Insert new Attachment with the new Juridical_Attachments__c record as parent
    *  3. Update the Juridical_Attachments__c record with the ID of the new Attachment
    **/
    public PageReference processUpload() {
        try {
            Database.SaveResult customAttachmentResult = saveCustomAttachment();
        
            if (customAttachmentResult == null || !customAttachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                  'Could not save attachment.'));
                return null;
            }
        
            Database.SaveResult attachmentResult = saveStandardAttachment(customAttachmentResult.getId());
        
            if (attachmentResult == null || !attachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                  'Could not save attachment.'));            
                return null;
            } else {
                // update the custom attachment record with some attachment info
                Juridical_Attachments__c customAttachment = [select id from Juridical_Attachments__c where id = :customAttachmentResult.getId()];
                customAttachment.name = this.fileName;
                customAttachment.Attachment__c = attachmentResult.getId();
                update customAttachment;
            }
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.AddMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        
        return new PageReference('/'+caso.id);
    }
    
    public PageReference back() {
        return new PageReference('/'+caso.id);
    }     

}
```

ApexControllerTest:

```java
@isTest
public class UploadAttachmentController_Test {


         @isTest static void testProcessUpload(){
                   // set the page
                    test.setCurrentPageReference(page.UploadAttachment);
                    //create the case here 
                    case c = new case();
                    c.Assunto__c = 'Assunto';
                    c.Description = 'Draft';
                    insert c;
                    
                    //create the Juridical_Attachments__c here
                    Juridical_Attachments__c j = new Juridical_Attachments__c();
                    j.Case__c = c.id;
                    j.description__c = c.Description;
                    j.Name = 'html';
                    j.Attachment__c = '123456789012345678';
                    insert j;

                    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
                    UploadAttachmentController ucac = new UploadAttachmentController(sc);
                  
                    //fill page variables
                    ucac.selectedType = 'VALUE';
                    ucac.description = 'VALUE';
                    ucac.fileName = 'FILE NAME';
                    ucac.fileBody = blob.valueOf('abcd');
                    test.startTest();
                    //click the button 
                    ucac.processUpload();
                    test.stopTest();

          }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "It's returning null"? where is it returning null? What do you expect it to do?  You've included a whole bunch of information but it's not clear what the actual problem is

Comment: does it return `NULL` in tests also? Because in screenshot I don't see you opening VF page or passing Id of Case

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.

But the problem is that the controller should get the value of the registry that is starting the process and that doesn't happen.

On the screen I went through it was to demonstrate that the case id is null and should be filled.

Comment: In the: 

    public UploadAttachmentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        this.caso = (Case)controller.getRecord();
        System.debug(this.caso);
    } 

It just goes null and nothing I do makes it resolve.

Comment: @NickCook can you help me now?

Comment: @ytiq can you help me now?

Comment: do you pass `Id=d32r32rji23rj` (caseId) in URL?

Comment: @ytiq sorry, how can I do this? I'm a very Beginner Programmer.

Comment: how does this VF page get launched? from a custom button on the Case detail page?

Comment: @cropredy yes, it is

Comment: what does the custom button look like (its configuration)?

Comment: @cropredy You were right. They put a - instead of =.
5 days working for a simple thing like that. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL no longer exists when clicking a custom button is usually indicative of a mis-constructed URL expression in the custom button

For example, if the Custom button URL is defined as

```
/apex/uploadAttachment?id-500xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

instead of

```
/apex/uploadAttachment?id=500xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

the URL is uninterpretable by Salesforce.

Of course, the example above is only one possibility. There are many other possibilities:

- the id parameter is not a valid SFDC Id or represents an Id of a deleted record
- the second, 3rd, etc parameters aren't preceded by `&=`
- you are using a merge field that doesn't resolve to a valid ID

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But could you help me with this question too?  
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350703/when-creating-a-visualforce-that-is-called-by-a-button-it-gets-that-name-in-the

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/353160/100934