# When creating a visualforce that is called by a button it gets that name in the console case and I can't remove it

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, css, html

When creating a visualforce that is called by a button it gets that name in the console case and I can't remove it.

What would be the solution.

[image]

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="UploadAttachmentController" title="Anexos Juridicos">

 <apex:sectionHeader title="{!Case.CaseNumber}" subtitle="Attach File"/>

   <apex:form id="form_Upload">
 
    <apex:pageBlock >
 
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
     <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Voltar"/>
     <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Cancelar"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 
  <apex:pageMessages />
 
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Arquivo" for="file_File"/>
    <apex:inputFile id="file_File" value="{!fileBody}" filename="{!fileName}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel value="Descrição" for="description"/> 
  <apex:inputTextarea id="description" value="{!description}" rows="4" cols="50"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel value="" for="uploadBtn"/> 
    <apex:commandButton id="uploadBtn" value="Adicionar Anexo Privado" action="{!processUpload}" />
    <!--  <apex:outputlink id="uploadBtn" value="Adicionar Anexo Privado" action="{!processUpload}" /> -->
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>    

   </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>


 </apex:form>

<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/52.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testSetTabTitle() {
        sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(function(result) {
           sforce.console.setTabTitle('Anexos Juridicos', result.id);
        });
}
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: you need to look at the [Service Console Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console.htm) as there are APIs that can manipulate the tabname. See `setTabTitle` method.  You should use [edit] and amend your post to focus on this specific issue as the controller/testmethod are irrelevant here - only the VF page (which will need some JS)

Comment: @cropredy Can you help me now?
I put this piece of code at the end of my visualforce what now?

Comment: so -- I think you are using the [wrong example from the doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_settabtitle.htm). You are using the second example, and should be using the first since the VF is launched from a custom button